# Not able to navigate to tab app in dev environment in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

I am working on a Microsoft teams tab app. The app has 2 tabs. The app is installed in a team.
For testing i have deployed it on Edge browser using the "Preview your Teams app" action in VS Code, using the Teams Toolkit extension.

What i am trying to achieve is that if i share a url of one of the tabs on a group chat of that team, then on clicking that url, that tab of the app opens.

The url that i have made is of this format -
[https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/${appId}/tabId](https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/$%7BappId%7D/tabId)

Here the `appId` is

```
const appId = environment === "local" ? constants.TEAMS_APP_ID_LOCAL : constants.TEAMS_APP_ID_DEV;
```

So the final url us something like - https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/fe4a8eba-2a31-4737-8e33-e5fae6fee194/tabId

But when i click on the link i see this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz2kM.png)

So, by clicking above link i am not able to navigate to the app's tab.

Any idea what i may be doing wrong here? or how can u fix it so that on clicking the tab's link it redirects me to that tab of the app.

Comment: Could you please follow the below document to generate deeplink to Tab-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-application?tabs=teamsjs-v2#generate-a-deep-link-to-your-tab

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I followed this document only and using it made the link https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/fe4a8eba-2a31-4737-8e33-e5fae6fee194/tabId   Is there any issue with this link..?

Comment: -Could you please Reshare the deeplink properly. We are not able to check the deeplink URL.

Comment: We have tried the below deeplink for navigate the tab and it is working fine from our end.
   `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/61c7fc2e-43d3-41a8-9956-313eXXXXXXX/DetailsTabDemo?context={"chatId":"19%3Ameeting_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40thread.v2","contextType":"chat"}`

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, thank you for the help. i found the issue. somehow the appId that was coming in onstants.TEAMS_APP_ID_LOCAL was not the right appId in the constants file. when i checked with that appId it seems to work fine. thank you for your help!